# Vue Micro UI/Web Components Development Workflow

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

Seeking some ideas on how to better improve my teams local development workflow...

We have a Vue CLI shell application project that runs locally via node. Then we have a number of small Vue CLI web-component applications that served up via node.

When the shell is ran it reaches out to each web-component application retrieving a manifest.json file which tells the shell where/when to display the respective web-components.

Our web-component applications are built using something like...

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name foo 'src/components/*.vue'
```

Having to continuously build the web-component projects after making a code change... debug... and then rebuild again seems cumbersome. This is a new application so at the moment the codebase is in constant flux.

Was hoping someone may have suggestions on how or tools we might use to increase our productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things.

Here's [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)

As far as I can tell it does everything you want to do straight out of the box. Just set up a basic hello world project with Nuxt and see if it does everything you need it to do for you. It uses Vue.js and Webpack to build the exact same type of application you'd be developing otherwise with Vue, it just has a nicer layout and easier workflow in general. It supports hot reloading on file changes, you'd just run `nuxt` in the root folder of your project and a local server is started that hot reloads your project whenever you save changes to a file. You then distribute it either as a static application with `nuxt generate` or build it as a server side rendered application using `nuxt build` and `nuxt start`.